# Condicion dentro de TRY CATCH SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo esta query

```
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT  @cumplimiento = (   
                        (
                            (@verde+(0.5 * @amarillo))
                            /   (@diasTrabajados)
                        )
                           * 100
                   ) 

  SELECT 'Estoy en bloque TRY';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 'Error --- Estoy en bloque CATCH';
END CATCH
```

lo que quiero realizar es una condición , si @ cumplimiento es igual a 0 me atrape el error  en el catch ,pero no entiendo muy bien como manejar la condición

Comment: Porque querrias forzar un error, cuando es algo que podrias hacer en un if y devolver lo que quisieras?

Comment: O sea, quieres forzar un error para un valor de `@cumplimiento`?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr con esto?, pregunto porque puede ser que estemos ante un [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te podría servir...
BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate divide-by-zero error.
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;
END CATCH;

Es para cachar una division entre 0, aqui la documentación:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Y que tiene que ver esto con la pregunta? Podrias mirar [answer]?

Answer (score 0):

Puesto que un valor de cero no genera ningún error, lo que debes hacer es generar un error personalizado usando [RAISERROR()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql).

```
DECLARE @cumplimiento decimal(10, 2),
        @verde decimal(10, 2) = 0,
        @amarillo decimal(10, 2) = 0,
        @diasTrabajados decimal(10, 2) = 10
BEGIN TRY
  SELECT  @cumplimiento = (   
                        (
                            (@verde+(0.5 * @amarillo))
                            /   (@diasTrabajados)
                        )
                           * 100
                   ) 
  -- Aquí está el cambio
  IF @cumplimiento = 0
    RAISERROR( N'El Cumplimiento es igual a cero', 11, 1);
  -- Aquí termina el cambio

  SELECT 'Estoy en bloque TRY', @cumplimiento;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 'Error --- Estoy en bloque CATCH', @cumplimiento;
END CATCH
```